# I'm trying to match different tables without a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

before posting this, I searched for an answer, but couldn't find the exact solution to my issue.

First of all, I am only assuming that I need INNER JOIN to solve it. FULL OUTER JOIN might also do the trick.

I have 3 different tables in one database.

**TABLE 1**

| userId | roleID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

**TABLE 2**

| userId | userName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

**TABLE 3**

| roleId | roleName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |

My goal is to write a query, which matches the *userName* from Table 2 with the *roleName* of Table 3 in the output. It should look like this:

**Output**

| UserName | RoleName |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | Y |

I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
so far I am trying to modify the following query to do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM
table1.roleId 
INNER JOIN
table2.roleId 
ON table1.roleId = table3.roleId
INNER JOIN
table2.userId 
ON table2.userId = table3.roleId
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and `JOIN` again.  What have you tried?

Comment: Check this site : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_join.asp you should find useful hints

Comment: What's the problem with this? You can use a JOIN on pretty any column, so if you want to join on equal names, just do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join all tables together with following conditions:

1. Table 2 userId = Table 1 userId
2. Table 3 roleId = Table 1 roleId

Then select only those values which are relevant to you.

I think this should do the job:

```sql
select t2.userName, t3.roleName
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.userId = t1.userId
join table3 t3 on t3.roleId = t1.roleId;
```

The query above uses INNER JOINs to get the result.
If there are `userId`s without a `roleId` in Table 1, FULL OUTER JOIN would  also return userNames with empty roleNames if such entries are present.